Self hosting microsoft bot for teams channels
I saw answers of this on microsoft but seems nothing is well documented around this so still not sure what permissions and services I need to use from Azure and how to do this
What I need is to create a microsoft bot in C# [for teams channels] and self host it on my OWN machines
I saw I'll need ngrok to expose its endpoint and use that on an Azure Bot service.
But still, I don't know what exactly I do need and how to do so for a production environment.
Can someone please explain a step by step [like for a 5 years old boy] how can I deploy the bot on teams channels but have it self hosted?
Regards

I've given an answer below, but maybe give some background why you want/need to host this locally? You don't -have- to host on Azure, for instance, but I'd look to a cloud hosting option if possible for scale/resilience/etc.

So I need to self host the bot because it will run specific command on the machine where it will live

ok, I see. You still might want to run the bot itself elsewhere, and just expose this single capability via a web endpoint (e.g. a rest service), with appropriate security in place. Especially if your bot does other things, you might want to reduce it's possible fragility and downtime

it does not other things but I'll address this as having a service on the machine itself that will expose an API it may be a better solution in long run. we used slack bots that are easier but we need to migrate to ms, unfortunatelly :-)

I think that's a safer bet, for sure. As an example, if the API / connection is down for some reason, the bot if it's hosted separately and in a more resilient manner can have built in retries but also can give the user a response message, instead of just failing silently.

Can you please give me more details about how to securely self host the bot? I have the bit endpoint for registered app, but of course it is exposed publicly and not sure how to address this. In the end I'll the the endpoint to be added to the regostered app

This is a bit of a broad and many-layered question, but as a starting point maybe these can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/teams/securing-bot-teams-channel and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-overview

Yes this is totally possible, just not super well documented. I've got an answer to a similar question at Host bot on-premise? Bot needs to communicate with another program, so please review that first. Basically, in simple terms though, you need a "registration" of your bot in Azure, but not necessarily to host it there. However, I'd be careful about hosting it locally when there are great cloud options that provide good failover and recovery, perhaps better than we might be able to offer.

how can I add the azure bot to teams channels?

can you elaborate on your question - I'm not following you.

So I created the azure bot service and if I test it into the "test in web chat" it is working correctly. Yes I have in channels a way to open the bot on teams but I would like to attach the bot to a channel annd everyvbody from that channel to have access to it [having attached to a channel we'll have all the commands logged as well ...]

For that it must be deployed into Teams as a app, either via the global (Microsoft) App Store or just into your tenant's app store. See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-package
